# Can I use my current SharedPreferences tag to store the values from a PreferenceActivity?

Tags: android

Currently, I'm using the following code across all of my activities in my app to store application level variables and carry values between activities..

```
prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

I didn't have a PreferenceActivity prior to this, but now I do and I am looking to store a few user prefs from this new PreferenceActivity in the same sharedPreferences tag, "MyPrefs".

I know I can access the PreferenceActivity SharedPrefs from my activities via

```
prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

but I would like those values saved to my current sharedPreferences tag, "MyPrefs", but I'm not sure how to do this.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the default name of SharedPreferences file used by PreferenceActivity.
I did this in onCreate method of PreferenceActivity by adding the following piece of code:

getPreferenceManager().setSharedPreferencesName("MyPrefs");

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can http://idlesun.wordpress.com/2011/04/08/how-to-make-preferenceactivity-use-non-default-sharedpreferences/

Answer (score -1):

You can't. the PreferneceManager always uses **this.getPackageName () + "_preferences** as preference name. Sorry to break the bad news. This is also important when you wish to use the [new backup framework](http://my.opera.com/fx-602p/blog/2010/07/19/backup-getdefaultsharedpreferences).

You can of course replace MyPrefs with **this.getPackageName () + "_preferences**.